# RVM: Install Ruby, Bundler, and Rails but it doesn't "stick"

Tags: osx-lion, rvm

OK, I now done this three times, Google and search here doesn't seem to help. I have RVM installed on OS X Lion. I have two different Rails apps, one that 1.9.2 and one that 1.8.7.  However, ever time I go back into the app that 1.8.7 after closing my current terminal session, it says that I haven't installed ruby 1.8.7. The exact message is:

> ruby ruby-1.8.7-p352 is not installed.
>   To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p352'
>   Failed to create RVM environment 'ruby-1.8.7-p352@tat_store'.

I figured I was missing a path or something but no love. I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "/Users/Ross/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/Ross/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Driving me crazy, I can work on the app fine until I close the terminal window. To start woking again, I have to go through a full reinstall. Ideas?

Comment: Are you doing an `rvm use` of the correct Ruby version and gemset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruby `ruby-1.8.7-p352` is an older version, when you update rvm to stable/head - `rvm get stable` the expected behavior will be:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
... installing ruby-1.8.7-p357 ...
$ rvm use 1.8.7
... using ruby-1.8.7-p357 ...
```

if you would like to use older ruby patchlevel then you need to explicitly specify it:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7-p352
... installing ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
$ rvm use 1.8.7-p352
... using ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
```